# Ошибка: объект принадлежит другой сессии

Tags: c#, devexpress

```
using (Session sess = BVVGlobal.oXpo.Get_Session())
{
    set_User o_u = BVVGlobal.oXpo.Get_Session().GetObjectByKey<set_User>(us.Oid);
    List<set_Org> orgList = new List<set_Org>(); // Список организаций
    orgList.Clear();

    foreach (set_Org element in listBox2.Items)
    {
        orgList.Add(element);
    }    
    while (o_u.Orgs.Count != 0)
    {
        int iy = o_u.Orgs.Count;
        o_u.Orgs.Remove(o_u.Orgs[iy - 1]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < orgList.Count; i++)
    {
        o_u.Orgs.Add(orgList[i]);
    }

    o_u.Save();
}
```

Ругается на `o_u.Orgs.Add(orgList[i])`: говорит `*.set_Org'` объект принадлежит другой сессии. Как исправить?

Comment: Уточните, что такое `BVVGlobal`, `oXpo` и `Get_Session()`. Приведите [mcve]

Comment: Посмотрите сюда, может поможет - https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q364674

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous - откуда вы взяли слово "компилятор"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov из сообщения об ошибке. Его выдает XPO, девэкспрессовский ORM. Хотя могу ошибаться, конечно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov IDE? DevExpress -- это набор разнообразных компонент, от UI-контролов до ORM-фреймворка.

Comment: @andreycha хм, однако...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина ошибки заключается в том, код загружает объекты в две разные сессии, а затем объекты загруженные в одной сессии добавляет в коллекцию объектов загруженных в другой сессии. Это запрещено, потому что сессия должна мониторить состояние объектов и быть способной в любое время дать ответ на вопрос, к примеру, какие объекты были изменены. Поэтому чужеродные объекты (загруженные в другой сессии) отвергаются при попытке добавить их в коллекцию.

Исключение указывает на то место в коде, в котором это происходит, а сообщение об ошибке указывает ее причину. Для того чтобы исправить ошибку, необходимо найти код, который загружает объекты участвующие в операции, и изменить его таким образом, чтобы все объекты участвующие в операции загружались в одной сессии.

Если по какой либо существенной причине нельзя проконтроллировать загрузку объектов и обеспечить чтобы они загружались в одной сессии, то для того чтобы добавить объект загруженный в другой сессии в коллекцию, необходимо получить объект загруженный в нужной сессии используя метод [Session.GetObjectByKey](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXpoSession_GetObjectByKeytopic). При таком подходе изменения которые еще не были сохранены не будут применены к объекту, загруженному в другой сессии. Поэтому этот подход применим не всегда, и хорошей практикой является использование только одной сессии для загрузки объектов, необходимых в текущей операции.